# Mutate a column in an R dataframe from <chr> to a new column of <Date> type

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has been created as a result of importing a .CSV file.  An example of the dataframe is illustrated in the following image:

[image]

As you can see, the Order Time field comes in as <chr>.  I would like to mutate this column, creating a new column that is of type <Date>.  Now, I can get the new (mutated) column created, but the value in the new column (for each row) is the value of the first row in the dataframe:

[image]

Certainly seems like I'm missing something very trivial, but I have not been able to figure it out.  This is my first foray into the R programming language and R Studio (very impressed with both).

I am using the following line of code in an effort to attain the objective:

```
new_big_mac <- bigm_df %>% mutate(actual_date = ymd_hms(paste(substr(bigm_df[4], 4, 22))))
```

Comment: There are two issues here.  First, if you have one value repeated you are likely _not_ doing a 'column on column' operation but rather an accidental 'expand one row value to entire column'.  So check your indexing: in your code example the `bigm_df[4]` is a code smell.  Second, for time types, make sure you understand that you should a) always parse first (to `POSIXct`, likely) after which a formatting step is easier.  You can do all of this in base R, or, if you prefer with add-on packages.

Comment: Also, please don't post screenshots.  Small yet complete verifiable code examples are best and often lead to a volunteer helping you with a working code snippet.  "Help us help you" -- which is (much) harder from images.

Comment: `bigm_df %>% mutate(actual_date = ymd_hms(\`Order Time\`))`

Comment: I presume Onyambu's suggestion will work, but fyi the problem is that `bigm_df[4]` returns a data frame based on the 4th column -- you want to feed `substr` a vector, like `bigm_df[,4]`. Compare `substr(mtcars[4], 1, 20)` to
`substr(mtcars[,4], 1, 20)`.

Comment: Why the `substr`? Try `as.POSIXct('2022-01-21 00:09:50 +0000 UTC', tz='UTC')`.